# could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::string'

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

When I write such a code in visual studio:

```
void aaa()
{
    std::string a = " ";
    std::string b = "";
    b += 1.0f + a;
}
```

Why do I receive such an error? Where does `std::reverse_iterator` come from?

> error C2784: 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator +(reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::difference_type,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::string'

Comment: what is `1.0f` ?

Comment: @RoiHatam that's how you write floats

Comment: This is my foolish mistake. I forgot to use `std::to_string` for numbers.

Comment: The compiler probably tried multiple automatic conversions that would result in a sane outcome, and this one was the last one it tried before giving up. Had you written `b += 1 + " ";` then it would have found one and not given you an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, that's an expected error message from Microsoft compiler.

The reason it happens is because you included `<string>` header which defines a few `operator+` templates for different iterators:

```
        // reverse_iterator TEMPLATE OPERATORS
template<class _RanIt> inline
    reverse_iterator<_RanIt> operator+(
        typename reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::difference_type _Off,
        const reverse_iterator<_RanIt>& _Right)
    {   // return reverse_iterator + integer
    return (_Right + _Off);
    }
```

Since there is no `operator+` exists for adding floats and `std::string` your code won't compile. But during compilation compiler detected that above mentioned `std::operator+` might be possible candidate since your float can be converted to `reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::difference_type`. When it tried this `operator+` it wasn't able to deduce what type it should use in place of `_RanIt` to convert `std::string` to `const reverse_iterator<_RanIt>&` it work out.

As you noted, compiler then tries to match other versions of `operator+` for other iterator types:

> error C2784: 'std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> std::operator
>   +(_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size>::difference_type,std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size>)':
>   could not deduce template argument for
>   'std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size>' from 'std::string'
>
> error C2784: 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size> std::operator
>   +(_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size>::difference_type,std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size>)':
>   could not deduce template argument for
>   'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,_Size>' from 'std::string' ...

As a side note, in C++ you should first convert numbers to strings and then concatenate (e.g. add) them. This should work for you:

```
b += std::to_string(1.0f) + a;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavel. I am wondering why C++ is strict on not to define such an operator.

Comment: Because it's a bit awkward in c++ and not clear what float + string should do. You should do this instead: `std::to_string(1.0f) + a`

Comment: @fk-ken-white I would assume C++ doesn't define it because of what happens in languages like JavaScript, where it *is* permitted to "add" strings and numbers.  What does `"10" + 2` equal?  `"102"` or `12`? Of course if you know the rules you can figure it out, but it's better to be explicit so that the person reading your C++ code doesn't have to guess what you *meant.*  That's where developers lose the most time -- trying to figure out what the author meant to do. Leaving out these operators forces you to be explicit about your intent.

Comment: @cdhowie exactly.